# How important is Temperature?

Tags: prison-architect

In Update 4, Introversion introduced a Temperature system into the game, and in Updates 5 & 6 it was improved upon. I haven't built a prison with Temperature included, so how important is it? I know that there is a `Warmth` need and a `Frigid` effect, but I don't know how much they affect Prisoners. Is it necessary to build radiators in prisons?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not played the game fully since these updates went live.

From what I understand, prisoners can die of exposure. This can be a game over condition.

The "Frigid" effect will subdue a prisoner temporarily, but increase it's Warmth neeed a lot.

The "Warmth" need, like any need, must be fullfilled. Too many prisoners with unfulfilled needs will increase the danger level in your prison (sometimes also referred to as "temperature" for added confusion), which can start a riot, which can kill a lot of your prisoners too.

So yes: You must built radiators in at least some places, so the prisoners can fullfill their needs. If you feel particularly cruel, you can omit radiators in certain places to cause the "frigid" effect, to try to control your prisoners. As in any system in Prison Architect, that has it's downsides too.